# Double dot on spotlight calculator

Tags: spotlight

So I'm playing around with the Spotlight calculator, and came across a weird thing:

If I type

`1..1`, I receive `0.1`
`5..6`, I receive `3`
`523..6.1`, I receive `31.38`

Does anybody know what mathematical function this is?

Edit: This works on macOS Sierra 10.12.2, as for people in the comments, it looks like three dots are required on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: I don't get those results when I use Spotlight on my MBP on High Sierra.  I get a bunch of different answers but none of them is mathematical.

Comment: This doesn't work for me [with two dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCxXi.png), only [with three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWhkU.png)

Comment: Yep, 3 dots is what it takes.

Comment: @fsb Huh... Works perfectly fine for me with two. I'm on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening, is the calculator splits the numbers and dots into the following:

`5..6=3` turns into `5 * .6 = 3`

As we know that `.` is another way of saying 'multiply' its simply, 5 multiplied by .6

As for `523..6.1=31.38`, it turns into `523 * (.6 * .1) = 31.38`